# Get HTTP URL from href-attribute (All possible ways for links)

Tags: java, html, url

I am trying to do a simple script that will convert any possible HTML link into HTTP URL, such as

```
http://example.com //example.com /index.html ./index.html index.html
```

I already tried function that I found in another answer:

```
public static Integer isAbsoluteURL (String url) throws java.net.MalformedURLException {
    final URL baseHTTP = new URL("http://example.com");
    final URL baseFILE = new URL("file:///");
    if (url.length() > 0) {
        if (url.substring(0, 1) == "/") {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    URL frelative;
    URL hrelative;
    try {
        frelative = new URL(baseFILE, url);
        hrelative = new URL(baseHTTP, url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException found");
        return 3;
    }
    if (frelative.equals(hrelative)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to get absolute links, but the code don't work for ./, //(without http[s]).

Thanks.

Comment: *"works, but not for everything"*  --- [I downvoted because "it's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use spring's UriComponentBuilder which will take care about everything:

```
 https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder
```